# leading + trailing zeros on R

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, string-formatting

I want to format a number adding simultaneously leading and trailing zeros on R (or Python)

I need 5 caracters at the integer part and 2 at the decimal part

For example:

86.30 -> 00086.30

Comment: In R, use `sprintf`.

Comment: in python, use `str.zfill` and/or `str.format`.

Comment: I used sprintf in R, but i cant get simultaneously leading and trailing zeros

Comment: python: `"{:.2f}".format(86.30).zfill(8)`.

Comment: You can use `str_pad` ; `library(stringr);str_pad("86.30", 8, pad = "0")#[1] "00086.30"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options in `R`

**1)**  with `sprintf`

```
sprintf("%08.2f", 86.30)
#[1] "00086.30"
```

**2)** use `str_pad` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_pad("86.30", 8, pad = "0")
#[1] "00086.30"
```

Comment: To elaborate on the `sprintf` solution as formats are not so easy to understand from `?sprintf` : the `8` in the formula is the total number of characters, the `2` is the number of characters after the period. Note that it will round the number to the chosen number of decimals.